# how to make a enumeration field depend on another enumeration field in Orchard CMS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Consider that we have two fields of type enumeration field in Orchard CMS as follow:
First list contains state values:

> - Alabama
> - Alaska
> - Arizona
> - ...

and the second one contains the cities of the selected state. for example suppose we have selected the `Arizona` state, so we should see just the following items in the second drop down list:

> - Apache Junction
> - Avondale
> - Benson

and so on ...

is it possible to accomplish this by enumeration field or if not is there any other approach to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Taxonomies for that, as it allows for hierarchies of terms.

Comment: can you explain about it more in detail?